# Android SignIn Flow (Password Login) Confusion

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

I am testing out the GitKit V3 Android quickstart and everything works great except the Password Login. Every time I input some random email address for the first time, the SignIn flow will prompt me with a "Create new account" box. After I sign in, I was able to verify the tokens to extract the emails etc.

However, when I logout (delete my session token) and login again with the same email, I expect it to let me input my password but instead it prompts me with the "Create new account" box again. Here, if I try to input a new name and password, the box complains that the email already exists. I am not sure why this is the case since looking through the sample code only leads me to the startSignIn() method.

I think the quickstart works great for my app but I am wondering if I should be overriding the UI manager and implement my own signIn flow? Right now, I am thinking of using the fact that the box complains that the email exists (when you login after your initial first time) to prompt the user to enter passwords etc.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance!

PS - there's a similar question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-identity-toolkit/password/google-identity-toolkit/7UUInP3dvDo/3pA8UQqDagAJ) but the answer didn't help.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You may debug the app using Android Studio, and see whether there are some clues in the logcat. Also, have you tried to sign in using Google (or Facebook or other identity providers)?

Anyway, there is no need to override the UIManager if you just want to work around the password login issue. There are some relevant efforts ongoing and you may contact the Google Identity Toolkit team  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-identity-toolkit for details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did get the Google and Facebook sign in working which is why I am a bit confused. Will head over to the forum.