# Google Identity Toolkit for Android cannot sign in to existing accounts (Password login)

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit

so we've been trying to implement logging in for our Android application, and we've hit a roadblock with the Google Identity toolkit where we have this exact problem:

[Android SignIn Flow (Password Login) Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801294/android-signin-flow-password-login-confusion/31865894)

[Google forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-identity-toolkit/android/google-identity-toolkit/4btTgrbPDYY/mbzsfh0zCwAJ)

It seems like it's a problem in the Android client, and since the GitKitClient doesn't have available source code, nor can you extend it, we're a bit stuck.

We've got the web page up and running on our local server and we can login to existing accounts there.

We've seen that the forums said that Google employees would monitor this tag, so hopefully they can help.

We've been playing around with a CustomUiManager to try and get a workaround but no dice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

we are investigating the problem, but can not consistently reproduce the issue. Will update here and the forum thread once we identify the root cause.

Comment: Can you tell us any way to workaround the issue? Maybe there's an option using the pure Java client? 

Thanks for getting back so quick!